# Solving PLL Loop BW Transfer Function

Tags: transfer-function, bandwidth, control-loop

()=  (1+.2.2)/(.(3.^3+2.^2+1.+0)

C2 = 0.0000001F

R2 = 1000 Ohm

A0 = 0.000000106034

A1 = 1.27859848E-12

A2 = 4.5011166848E-18

A3 = 4.31278848E-24

G()=  (..())/

KPD = 0.005 A

KVCO = 30000000 Hz/V

S = jω

Magnitude |G(jω)| = N

N = 4500

Can someone expert derive and prove that ω = 31954.3955167232 or BW = ω/2π = 5.0857kHz?

Comment: you might need to define what some of those terms mean, with reference to a schematic

Comment: And also show what numbers have you arrived at, and how. Welcome to the site!